# Single log out for oauth connected app

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, connected-apps, oauth

We’ve followed this guide for single logout (SLO) to call the logout url of our connected app.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage_oauth.htm&type=5
Specifically:
“ If you selected Enable Single Logout, enter a single logout URL. Salesforce sends logout requests to this URL when users log out of Salesforce. The single logout URL must be an absolute URL starting with https://.”

However, our connected app has multiple live sessions, the browser holds the current session cookie for our connected app’s domain. This cookie isn’t sent when Salesforce requests the connected apps logout url.

Is there anyway to pass user/session data on the logout url from Salesforce to our connected app?

Comment: Hi I've same issue, Have you resolved it? Could you help share some insight of this, please?